# Pandas Concat - gspread worksheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, gspread

I am trying to concat a list of worksheets. I have read in a google sheet using `client.open_by_url()`.

I have tried:

```py
worksheet_list = spreadsheet.worksheets()
df = pd.concat(worksheet_list, ignore_index=True)
```

But get this error: `"TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'gspread.models.Worksheet'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"`

The question is does anyone know how to concat worksheets of the `gspread.models` type.

Any help is much appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worksheet object is the wrong type to `concat`. You need to change it to a pandas DataFrame before merging.

```
 #Iterate to get dataframes.
 list_of_dfs = [pd.DataFrame(ws.get_all_records()) for ws in worksheet_list] 

 # Concat the list of dataframes
 df = df.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It should be pd.concat() not df.concat()